# Binomial formula for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, binomial-theorem

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ that do not commute, i.e., $A B \neq B A$. Thus, if I apply the binomial formula, I get

$$ (A+B)^{n} \neq (B+A)^{n}$$

This is my own deduction. I haven't found any theorem about this property. Do you know if there exists one?

Comment: I reckon that there is no way you can get $(A+B)^n\ne (B+A)^n$.

Comment: There is no binomial formula for non-commutative matrices.

Comment: What principle forbids to use binomial formula for non-commutative matrices ?

Comment: Demonstrate how you apply it.

Comment: You already said it why you can't. It's because multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: But, i could write the binomial formula for 2 non-commutative matrices specifying the order of multiplications. This should work, no ?

Comment: I'm saying that , to me, it would be still possible to use binomial formula for 2 non-commutative matrices, in fact, even if $(A+B)^{n} \neq (B+A)^{n}$, the binomial formula gives a correct value for $(A+B)^{n} $ and a correct value for $(B+A)^{n}$

Comment: As the addition of matrices is commutative and any matrix commutes with itself $(A+B)^n=(B+A)^n$ for any $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As others have remarked, $(A+B)^n=(B+A)^n$ for arbitrary square matrices $A$, $B$. The problem is with the binomial formula.

If you want to compute, e.g., $(A+B)^3$ for two matrices $A$, $B$ then the distributive law generates $8$ terms as follows:
$$(A+B)^3=A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3\ .\tag{1}$$
When the matrices commute then you can write each of these terms in the form $A^jB^k$ and then collect similar terms. This leads to the binomial formula
$$(A+B)^3=\sum_{k=0}^3{3\choose k}A^{3-k}B^k\ .\tag{2}$$
When the matrices $A$ and $B$ do not commute then $(1)$ is still true, but it is forbidden to convert the $2^n$ terms of $(1)$ into the $n+1$  simpler terms appearing in $(2)$.