# Binomial formula for matrices and commutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754278/binomial-formula-for-matrices.%C3%B9) post it's said that in order to use the binomial formula to 2 matrices A and B : $(A+B)^{n}$

the two matrices must be commutative.
To me , it's sufficient that only **one** matrix is commutative. Is this true ?

Comment: What do you think "commutative" means?

Comment: $(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$ iff $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A+B=C$. As addition is always commutative over matrices, $B+A=C$ also.

So $(A+B)^n=C^n=(B+A)^n$, so $AB=BA$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ must be multiplicably commutative for the binomial theorem to provide a unique result.

[Commutative](https://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html) is a property of a [binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation), and thus takes two operands to function properly.

Comment: However , it's sufficient that A OR B commutes with every nxn matrix ?

Comment: A only needs to commute with B in this case