# Matrix binomial expansion

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra, binomial-theorem

Given two $n\times n$ adjacency matrices $A,B$ where $A_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, A_{ii}=0, A_{ab}=0$ and $B$ is a matrix with only a single element $B_{ab}=1$ and zero everywhere else. Is there a formula for performing the calculation $(A+B)^3$? I think that I can use binomial expansion only if A and B commute. I am struggling to determine whether or not this is always possible with my setup.

Thanks in advance, Ben

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754278/binomial-formula-for-matrices

Comment: Thanks @NoChance

Comment: So $(A+B)^3=A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3$ is fine to use.

Comment: I guess so, given that A, B are square matrices.